# google map error

Tags: android, google-maps, noclassdeffounderror

hi i want to use google map for my application all class i have built but when i call the class in which i map the google map code means extends MapActivity this class create error

ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.me.androidapplication5.NewClass

so please give me the solution for this type of error

Comment: Upload the code here. so that we can analyze it and guide you what the problem is and how it can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check which android API you selected you need the android API with Google map, chheck project properties and select Google Api